# IntelliCode adds star on autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, intellicode

After restarting vscode whenever I try to use an autocomplete suggestion from IntelliCode, it also includes the recommended star thing.
[issue video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Qcmvy_gx-w)

I have tried switching to an older version of intelliCode, disabling all my other extensions, switching to a new profile, and resetting my vscode settings.

I have also searched google, but was unable to find anyone else with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commit has been pushed to fix this already, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/172616.  I would think it'll be in the next Stable Release next week.

---

Looks like it is a new reported issue from multiple users.  See [Committing completion in a TS file inserts a star character](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/issues/431).

Just filed 01/25/2023.  I suggest you upvote and comment if your use case is different than those already presented.  And keep an eye on that issue if there is some sort of a fix posted.  It should be a simple fix, someone changed the mapping from the suggestion to the actual inserted completion.

[Also incorrectly reported at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/172419 - it is an extension issue so the first link is where to respond.]